# ASP.NET Identity - how to get all roles and how to delete a role?

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.net Identity with Web Forms in VS 2013 Express for Web.
I am referring to this AspIdentitySample example at https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample
The example is with MVC.
To get all roles and to delete a role, they use:

```
RoleManager.Roles()
RoleManager.DeleteAsync()
```

But I cannot find these two methods in my RoleManager - I mean they don't appear in Intellisense at all.
Are they only available in MVC, but not in Web Forms?

I am very frustrated with this Asp.net Identity stuff, is there any ASP.NET Identity books so that I can learn?

Comment: You might be looking at code that's written for v2 of the API ([it's in preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx)). The v1 documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468201(v=vs.111).aspx You probably want to delete them from your users and then your RoleStore instead. *is there any ASP.NET Identity books* => it's too new. You have to use the MSDN Blogs as reference material.

Answer (score 2):

This is how i get the roles in a dropdownlist

```
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>());
            var roles = roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            dropRolesDelete.DataTextField = "Name";
            dropRolesDelete.DataValueField = "Id";
            dropRolesDelete.DataSource = roles;
            dropRolesDelete.DataBind();
```

And this is how i use the dropdown list to delete a role

```
   try
        {
            var selecteditem = dropRolesDelete.SelectedItem.ToString();
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>());
            var role = roleManager.FindByName(selecteditem);
            roleManager.Delete(role);
            lblResult.Text = "Lucky"
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            lblResult.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

you may have to include this if you dident already

```
using ASP.NET_Identity.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```